# Having a unique set of JSON string in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

If I create a column in cassandra with `favorites set<text>` syntax, and insert JSON string in that column. Would it maintain a unique set of JSON string. By that I mean that if I enter 2 identical JSON string, would it store only one version of it in the column.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

eg:

> INSERT INTO users (user_id, first_name, last_name, favorites)
>          VALUES('smith', 'Will', 'Smith', {'cats', 'cats'});

will result in

> smith,"{'cats'}",Will,Smith

Hope it helps!